# What to do when a client cancels the deal but uses your concept?

Tags: logo, client-relations

Hello fellow designers,

Some time ago, a client requested me a logo design for his new company.
After I showed him some rough concepts, we came to an agreement on what the final logo should look like. However, he refused to pay (saying he expected to pay 200€ at max for 3 logos and a style guide) and the deal was cancelled.

I visited his website and noticed [the final logo](http://orion9.net/_demos/pimpMyAds/pimpMyAds_final.png):

[image]

he uses commercially bears a resemblance to [the concept](http://orion9.net/_demos/pimpMyAds/pimpMyAds_concept.png) I had sent him:

[image]

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Is that a font or custom, hand drawn lettering?? That may make a big difference. If he can just purchase the same font... well.... Ultimately, this is a matter to discuss with an attorney.

Comment: The website you posted, is that theirs? I wonder if they know that their website hierarchy is publicly accessible.

Comment: Consult with a lawyer.

Comment: The font is [bello](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/underware/bello/pro/), it can be bought for £35. I guess that if they can just buy that font all they have done is arrange the wording. Can much be done about that?

Answer (score 16):

Get a lawyer who specializes in intellectual property or copyright infringement and have the person review your contract. Depending on the wording and your local laws, you might have standing to sue for cease-and-desist or your full contract payment.

*(Next time, don't accept a job from someone who thinks "pimp" is a term which business professionals use to sell services.)*

Comment: Good advice in both paragraphs. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think we all get hit by this sometime in our careers. My advice is to save your money (Law is expensive), put it down to experience and spend your money getting a specialist lawyer draw up a watertight contract for you to use in the future. Good Luck.

Comment: Depends on your locale. In US yes here its loser pays so if you have a standing its not expensive.,

Comment: Over in the UK, they don't do a 'no win no fee' for this sort of think. The lawyers just sent letters back and forth to each other clarifying points, one letter per point, at about £50 per letter, so that if you win they take all the money and if you lose you pay them all the money. a lose lose situation. A bit like drowning a woman to prove she is not a witch, you die either way. :-(